# Rounded check box using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox

I am trying to create rounded style checkbox using Jquery mobile. In the below link, under multiple selects, choose option select menu i saw this type of checkbox. Is it possible to create that type of checkbox in listview of JQM?

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/selects/custom.html#&ui-state=dialog

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="options">
    <li data-icon="checkbox-off"><a>test</a></li>
    <li data-icon="checkbox-on"><a>test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah i needed checkbox like this, but not in icon format.Also user should enable or disable the checkbox on his/her own wish, not as above default On/Off state. I want to style the JQM form elements checkbox in rounded format. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet makes round edges for listview, you can have any element inside it:

```
<ol data-role="listview">
                    <li class="ui-corner-bottom ui-corner-top" data-theme="a" ><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-corner-bottom ui-corner-top" data-theme="a"><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-corner-bottom ui-corner-top" data-theme="a"><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
    </ol>
```

See the Demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/qXr79/5/